# Create an eclipse plugin with dependency on a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have a maven project that contains a certain api I need to use in an eclipse plugin. This eclipse plugin is not currently a maven project but a normal eclipse plugin project with a manifest. I converted this plugin project to a maven project (using m2e menu command to change project to maven) I added the dependency to the maven project from this project. My maven build for this project is running fine from command line. Now when I launch the eclipse application I am getting a ClassNotFoundException for the api I am referring to from the plugin project. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding tyco configuration to the maven project. That enables you to have a maven project with a Manifest thus enabling other plugins to depend on it. More info: http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/